# Agregar una letra al final de cada string en un array (JavaScript)

Tags: javascript, array, bucle-for

Estoy aprendiendo JavaScript, y practicando me tope con este ejercicio el cuál no sé como resolver, gracias de antemano a quien me pueda explicar cómo y por qué.

Consigna del ejercicio:Dados estos tres arrays:

​​​​carnivores = ['lion', 'shark', 'wolve', 'puma', 'snake'];

herbivores = ['elephant', 'giraffe', 'gacelle', 'hippo', 'koala'];

omnivores = ['human', 'monkey', 'dog', 'bear', 'pig'];

1. Define una variable llamada animals que referencie a los arrays anteriores: [carnivores, herbivores, omnivores].
2. Crea un bucle FOR que cambie cada string en el array de cada dieta para que sean plurales. Por ejemplo: ['lion',...] -> ['lions',...]

En donde tengo problemas para resolver es en el punto 2, les dejo mi código:

```
var carnivores = ['lion', 'shark', 'wolve', 'puma', 'snake'];
var herbivores = ['elephant', 'giraffe', 'gacelle', 'hippo', 'koala'];
var omnivores = ['human', 'monkey', 'dog', 'bear', 'pig'];

var animals = [].concat(carnivores, herbivores, omnivores);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Para resolver con lo que estás sugiriendo podrías hacer lo siguiente, sencillamente se recorre animals que es el resultado de la concatenación de todos los arrays y a todos los elementos les agrega una "s".

```
var carnivores = ["lion", "shark", "wolve", "puma", "snake"];
var herbivores = ["elephant", "giraffe", "gacelle", "hippo", "koala"];
var omnivores = ["human", "monkey", "dog", "bear", "pig"];

var animals = [].concat(carnivores, herbivores, omnivores);

for (let i = 0; i < animals.length; i++) {
  animals[i] = animals[i] + "s";
}

console.log(animals);
```

---

De acuerdo a la letra animal es un array que referencia a los anteriores, luego de cada array se recorre cada item agregandole la "s".
Para ese caso se podría hacer algo así:

En este ejemplo se recorre el array de animals y se usa como referencia para recorrer cada array en el primer for, en el segundo se recorre cada item dentro de ese array y a cada item le agrega una "s" al final.

```
var carnivores = ["lion", "shark", "wolve", "puma", "snake"];
var herbivores = ["elephant", "giraffe", "gacelle", "hippo", "koala"];
var omnivores = ["human", "monkey", "dog", "bear", "pig"];

var animals = [carnivores, herbivores, omnivores];

for (let dieta = 0; dieta < animals.length; dieta++) {
  for (let animal = 0; animal < animals[dieta].length; animal++) {
    animals[dieta][animal] = animals[dieta][animal] + "s";
  }
}

console.log(animals);
```

---

Unas posibles mejoras podrían ser las siguientes:
Este ejemplo hace lo mismo que el anterior, solo que en lugar de usar 2 for convencionales utiliza un for of, lo cual ayudará a la legibilidad.
También en la asignación se usa +=, para que se entienda esto:
`a = a + b` es equivalente a `a += b`.

```
var carnivores = ["lion", "shark", "wolve", "puma", "snake"];
var herbivores = ["elephant", "giraffe", "gacelle", "hippo", "koala"];
var omnivores = ["human", "monkey", "dog", "bear", "pig"];

var animals = [carnivores, herbivores, omnivores];

for (const dieta of animals) {
  for (let animal = 0; animal < dieta.length; animal++) {
    dieta[animal] += "s";
  }
}

console.log(animals);
```

---

En estos últimos 2 ejemplos la variable animals solo referencia a los difernetes arrays, y los arrays permanecen como estaban pero cada item ahora está en plural.

Answer (score 0):

aunque el for each es lo mejor para hacer eso, esta es una respuesta rapida y simple:

```
for (let animal = 0; animal < animals.length; animal++) {
  animals[animal] +='s'
  console.log(animals[animal]);
}
```

seteas "animal" en cero y recorres todo el array, ahi simplemente tomas cada elemento del array (animals[animal]) que es un string, y le sumas la 's'